# Is phosphorene a topological insulator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, topological-insulators, nanoscience

All of the other "-ene" materials (silicene, germanene, stanene, and even graphene) are topological insulators.  Phosphorene and these other materials all have honeycomb lattices and would appear to have similar properties.  However, I don't see any papers referring to phosphorene as a topological insulator, so is phosphorene just a semiconductor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is currently no evidence that it is a topological insulator - at least none of the 22 articles currently on arXiv containing phosphorene in the title mention anything of the sort.

But could it be? Well, I wouldn't get my hopes up at the moment. A key requirement for a topological insulator is band inversion (it is a necessary, but not sufficient condition), and first-principles calculations of the phosphorene band structure seem to suggest ordinary semiconductor gaps. See e.g. fig. 1 in [Liu et al. (2014)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4133).

Now, sometimes a band inversion can be driven by spin-orbit coupling (likely a weak factor for Phosphorous, given the low atomic mass), doping (as in silicene) or strain (as in stanene). At this point, I wouldn't want to rule out the possibility that it will be found in phospherene too. That said, [Peng et al. (2014)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3771) have already provided DFT calculations for phosphorene under strain, and don't seem to find any inversion.